# Python program to get all non unique elements in an array

Tags: python, beginner, array

Given an array of ints as input:

- non_unique([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]) returns [1, 3, 1, 3]
- non_unique([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) returns []
- non_unique([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]) returns [5,5,5,5,5]
- non_unique([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]) returns [10, 9, 10, 10, 9]

The code itself:

```
def checkio(originalList: list) -> list:

    checked_list = []
    result_list = []

    for i, number in enumerate(originalList):
        if number in checked_list:
            result_list.append(number)
        else:
            if (len(originalList) - 1) - i > 0:
                if number in originalList[i+1:]:
                    result_list.append(number)
        checked_list.append(number)

    return result_list
```

**How can be the code improved?**

Answer (score 4):

One thing to keep in mind is your variable `checked_list`, which serves almost no purpose in the function, as you could do without the else block.

The simplest thing I can think of would be just to shorten the function down to one list comprehension, instead of appending to two lists.

Revised code:

```
def checkio(original_list: list) -> list:
    return [x for x in original_list if original_list.count(x) > 1]
```

When running this function, these are the outputs:

```
checkio([1, 2, 3, 1, 3])  # Returns [1, 3, 1, 3]
checkio([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  # Returns []
checkio([5, 5, 5, 5, 5])  # Returns [5,5,5,5,5]
checkio([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8])  # Returns [10, 9, 10, 10, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Code Review

Keeping your current structure, I would modify your solution like this:

```
def checkio(originalList: list) -> list:

    result_list = []

    for i, number in enumerate(originalList):
        if number in originalList[:i] or number in originalList[i + 1:]:
            result_list.append(number)

    return result_list

checkio([1, 2, 3, 1, 3])         # Returns [1, 3, 1, 3] 
checkio([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])         # Returns []
checkio([5, 5, 5, 5, 5])         # Returns [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
checkio([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8])   # Returns [10, 9, 10, 10, 9]
```

The `if` condition now checks if the element in question appears anywhere else in the list. If so, the element is saved as it is non-unique. Compared to your solution, this function combines the `if` and `else` conditions into one check. It also removes `checked_list`.

To do this task in the most concise way, I would use list comprehension and the `Counter` subclass from the `collections` module, as shown below.

#### Another Approach

```
from collections import Counter

def checkio(originalList: list) -> list:
    counter = Counter(originalList)                       # Create "Counter" object
    return([x for x in originalList if counter[x] > 1])   # Return only non-unique elements

checkio([1, 2, 3, 1, 3])         # Returns [1, 3, 1, 3] 
checkio([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])         # Returns []
checkio([5, 5, 5, 5, 5])         # Returns [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
checkio([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8])   # Returns [10, 9, 10, 10, 9]
```

`counter` counts the occurrences of each element in the list and returns a dictionary. Here's an example:

```
Counter([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8])
# Counter({10: 3, 9: 2, 8: 1})
```

After creating this object, the function uses list comprehension and only adds elements that appear more than once, ie non-unique elements.

This answer is similar to snarp's. However, for large lists this version will be faster as the `Counter` object is computed only once (instead of calling `original_list.count(x)` for every element).

A bit more about the `collections` module: it has specialized data types with interesting advantages over standard Python objects such as `dict`, `list`, `set`, etc. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) is a link to the documentation.